# Group recurring values from a flat array into their own respective subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

I have an array that that I would like convert to a 2d array by grouping identical values together.

Once all elements with the same values have been pushed into the group, I want to use that group for something, then continue the loop and setup the next group, until all content of the original `$array` has been used.

```
public function adjust($array){ 
  // $array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 9, 20]
 
  $group = array()

  for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){
   // code here
   // result should be $group = [1, 1] 
   // use $group for something, reset its contents, 
   // continue loop until group is [2, 2],
   // rinse and repeat
 }    
}
```

I don't necesarrily need a loop, I just require to be able to slice `$array` into 5 `$groups` (for this specific example), to be able to process the data.

Is there an easier way to solve this without a bunch of if/else conditions?

Comment: Do you want something like this? 
`[[1, 1], [2, 2], [8, 8, 8], [9], [20]]`

Comment: No, thats not necesarry. Basicly, the bottom anwers are ok, though ideally i wouldnt want to process the last chunk outside the loop. Thanks.

Comment: I think use some library is easier. Have you ever used Laravel and its collections? I think its awesome! You can use them outside and Laravel/Lumen using this project https://github.com/tightenco/collect and you still all the laravel documentation!

Comment: Ill look into it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `$chunk` to an array containing the first element. Then loop through the rest of the array, comparing the current element to what's in `$chunk`. If it's different, process `$chunk` and reset it.

```
$chunk = array[$array[0]];
for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if ($array[$i] != $chunk[0]) {
        // use $chunk for something
        $chunk = array($array[$i]);
    } else {
        $chunk[] = $array[$i];
    }
}
// process the last $chunk here when loop is done
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_count_values` is more or likely what you want.

```
$array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 9, 20];
foreach (array_count_values($array) as $val => $count) {
    $chunk = array_fill(0, $count, $val); // contains [1, 1], [2, 2], etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without any conditions and without pre-grouping with `array_count_values()`.  No iterated function calls are necessary.  Just use each value as a temporary grouping key as you push each value into their own dedicated subarray.  This technique will group values even if recurring values are not consecutive.  If you want to remove the temporary keys, just call `array_values()`.

Language Construct Loop: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gib7V))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result[$value][] = $value;
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Functional Loop: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/M0kCI))

```
var_export(
    array_values(
        array_reduce(
            $array,
            function($result, $value) {
                $result[$value][] = $value;
                return $result;
            },
            []
        )
    )
);
```

Both output the following data structure:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [8, 8, 8], [9], [20]]
```